# What does it mean $f \mu$, when f is a function and $\mu$ a measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-chains

Let $f$ be a function and $\mu$ a measure.
I saw in Revuz's $\textit{Markov Chains}$ the following notation:
$$f \mu$$

What does it mean?

Thank you!

Comment: Then what does it mean the Radon - Nykodim derivative of $(f \mu)$?

Comment: If can denote a measure prescribed by $A\mapsto\int_Afd\mu$. But no guarantee. I don't have the book you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking Radon - Nykodim derivative describes the rate of change of density of one measure with respect to another